# Is it possible to create a bootable Windows drive with dd on WSL?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dd

The title pretty much sums it up. I would like to copy my current Windows HDD to a blank SSD over SATA using the `dd` command in WSL. It's 2019, and I don't want to boot from an HDD anymore. Would this work?

Comment: No it does not. Search "How to migrate Windows".

Comment: WSLv1 does not have access to every single directory within Windows.  I don't even believe WSLv2 will have the level of access that would be required to create an image of the system disk that would be required to do something like this.  There are far easier ways to create an image of a disk within Windows.